# How to delete entire row if two consecutive blanks exist in a column? VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Sample of Data]

I want to delete the row if two consecutive cells in a column are both blank.

```
Dim rngE As Range
Set rngE = Intersect(Range("E:E"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

If del Is Nothing Then
    Set del = cell
    Else: Set del = Union(del, cell)
    End If
End If

Next cell
On Error Resume Next
del.EntireRow.Delete
```

Here is how it should look when complete:
[image: Results]

Comment: where is `cell` come from?

Comment: maybe `if isEmpty(del) and isEmpty(del.Offset(0,1)) then del.delete`?

Comment: Do you mind sharing how your data is organized?

Comment: @simoco I defined cell and del above.. didnt include it in the code here

Comment: @L42 I am looking to delete all the values after the 4th column from the right where it is equal to 40. I want to keep this row, but delete all others. It will not always be 40 and none of the other values will be the same always either

Comment: Apologies @JDS but I'm still confused which row you want deleted and which not. Can you somehow show the resulting data?

Answer (score 0):

```
'this sub routines deletes all consecutive blank rows except one from 
'current sheet
'prakash b bajaj

Sub Delete_Consecutive_BlankRows_Except_One()


Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim LastUsedRow As Long
On Error Resume Next
Dim i As Long


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
LastUsedRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Set WorkRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastUsedRow, 1))

    For i = LastUsedRow To 1 Step -1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(WorkRng.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
           If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(WorkRng.Rows(i - 1)) = 0 Then
              WorkRng.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp
        End If
       End If
    Next

Cells(1, 1).Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```